# Firestore Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but ... has 3

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get object from Firestore and cast it to my type - "Task". But unfortunately I have this exception:
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users/gfaAubcGmZcmjElIrXcXs32vX023/notes has 3**

Here is my code for call object from Firestore:

```
override suspend fun getTasksById(taskId: String): Task? {
    return userId?.let { userId ->
        db.collection(COLLECTION_USERS)
                .document(userId)
                .collection(COLLECTION_NOTES)
                .document(taskId)
                .get()
                .await()
                .toObject(Task::class.java)
    }
}
companion object {
    const val COLLECTION_USERS = "users"
    const val COLLECTION_NOTES = "notes"
}
```

My Firestore structure - collection("users") -> document(userId) -> collection("notes") -> document(taskId). I counted 4 segments, and then I use get(). Why I receive that exception?

Comment: can you check taskID? It looks like it's empty.

Comment: Most likely the `userId` or `taskId` is empty. Can you please provide the actual values?

Comment: the reason was in taskId value indeed. I put incorrect values there.. Thank you for your answers)